# How to clear selectize.js dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox, selectize.js

Within the selectize.js library there are two methods to clear user input (**clear** and **clearOptions**). The problem with these methods are that they clear everything and I only need to clear the content of the dropdown list on close.

Currently this is what's occurring: I query the search box for a model, retrieve a list of models within the dropdown list, select the models I want, click away to close the dropdown list. Then when I go to query the search again I expect the dropdown list to be empty but it still contains the previous search results.

Is there a way to clear just the content of the dropdown list?

Below is the JavaScript for the list.

```
$('.model-select-dropdown').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'label',
    searchField: 'label',
    persist: false,
    options: [],
    load: function(query, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $i.contextPath + "/service/vehicle/model/suggestions/",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            data: {
                query: query,
                businessUnits: getSelectedBusinessUnits()
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The div for the dropdown list is `<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">`

I've tried clearing the content of the div by using the empty method.

`$('.model-select-dropdown').find('.selectize-dropdown-content').empty()`

With this I suspect the library is doing something in the background that keeps the content cached, as it removes the dropdown list but on click of the search box it brings the list back up.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear the selectize input by resetting the form. Not sure if that clears other fields you want to save, but worked for me.

document.getElementById('webinar-reg').reset();